# Testing for Consecutive Letters Between 2 Lists

Tags: python-3.x, list

Ive been struggling a bit in getting the logics for this one to work properly but simply put, id have 2 lists containing their own sets of characters. I should have it return where there are consecutive letters though im not capable of seeing the logic on my own, here is what i have so far

```
lst1=['k','u','h','m']
lst2=['k','u','h','n']
lst3=['s','y','u','u']
lst4=['p','y','u','u']
ns1=''
ns2=''
ns3=''
ns4=''
match1=0
match2=0

for x in range(0,len(lst1)-1):
    ns1=ns1+lst1[x]
    ns2=ns2+lst2[x]
    if ns1 == ns2:
        match1=match1+1
    return match1

for y in range(0,len(lst3)-1):
    ns3=ns3+lst3[y]
    ns4=ns4+lst4[y]
    if ns3 == ns4:
        match2=match2+1
    return match2
```

In the first for loop the expected output is 3 matches as there were 3 consecutive letters between lst1 and lst2, same with lst3 and lst4 though it should start from the second index.

Realistically this does work effectively but in the event of lst3 and lst4 it would return match1 as 3 as expected but in the event of match2, it would return a 0. Normally i could just begin the program with a range of 1 rather than 0, but in the event of a randomly generated list. How could i achieve the proper result?

As in the situation where theres 2 lists with:

```
lstx=['a','b','c','d']
lsty=['e','b','c','f']
```

with this example per say, the expected output should be 2 since b and c are consecutive between lstx and lsty

No matter what the expected output is minimum 2 as letters can only be classified as consecutive if there are 2 or more of them side by side and in the same position between its counterpart list

Comment: i order to clarify what you are asking can you provide the expected output for  your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem in your logic seem to be with nsX buffers you use inside the for loop, after failing the condition there is no reset in them so they can check other values since the carry along the mismatch from the first index.

Also it is easier to use `zip()` to iterate over the lists at the same time instead of using indexes and `range()` which should be avoided so your main loop can become like this:

```
for x, y in zip(lst3, lst4):
ns3 = ns3 + x
ns4 = ns4 + y
if ns3 == ns4:
    match2 = match2 + 1
else:
    ns3 = ''
    ns4 = ''
```

In your case i don't see anything done with the digits being consecutive, which can simplify your problem to which letters are the same in the same index of the lists, a much simpler check that can be done like this

```
count = sum(x == y for x, y in zip(lstx, lsty))
```

here zip() is used to itarate over both of the lists at the same time and the fact that sum() can sum values of false and true is used to to get how many times the condition x == y is true

Comment: Many thanks in your explanation, it was very helpful. Ill try to practice using the function a bit more to ensure I understand it fully

Comment: ask anything if you need clarification, also why was the consecutive part needed?

Comment: The assignment is a list check and i have the vast majority of the program where it accepts a sentence as a string, splits it and checks between a secondary sentence string, each are comprised into respective lists but the final part of the assignment is to do a string compare for words with similar vowel sounds, so sequential/consecutive letters should be checked if correct